# Sencha Touch 2 - Add (form) components in NestedList and scroll as one

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I have a panel which displays three components:

1. `Ext.field.Select`
2. `Ext.field.Search`
3. `Ext.data.NestedList`

Component 1 and 2 are used by the end-user to filter the lists content.

Both component 1 and 2 are added to the `NestedList` items collection after the `NestedList` is initialized. This works perfect. The issue here is that only the data in the `NestedList` scrolls. The other components stay on-top.

What I would like to achieve is that both component 1 and 2 stay on top of the `NestedList` and scroll together with the list. So if you would scroll down vertically, they would scroll out-of-screen.

Making the panel where the items reside in `scrollable: true` does not work because then the `NestedList` itself is being moved up/down and not the lists data.

Does anyone have some Pseude-code how I could achieve this? Or a direction in where I have to look? I played around with docking and several layout but it does not seem to work out. Maybe this is not (easily) possible with the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `scrollDock : 'top'` in your components config section. If you then add the component to a NestedList (or normal List) item collection, the component will stay on top - and scrolls nicely with the other list items.